Why is std::noop_coroutine() non-constexpr?
Currently, the signature of std::noop_coroutine() is without constexpr (cppreference.com):
inline std::noop_coroutine_handle noop_coroutine() noexcept {
    return noop_coroutine_handle();
}

(GCC libstdc++ source)
There is no way to define a constexpr noop_coroutine_handle:
constexpr std::noop_coroutine_handle noop = std::noop_coroutine();  // error

I understand the standard doesn't require it to be constexpr.
But is it intentional or something missing?
Actually, std::noop_coroutine_handle has a default (constexpr) constructor, though it's private (libstdc++ source).
And both std::coroutine_handle<void> and std::coroutine_handle<Promise> have constexpr constructors and from_address (except that from_promise is non-constexpr).
It seems unreasonable that we can define constexpr coroutine_handle's for void and all promises but not noop_coroutine_handle.
I tested locally and it's just a keyword away for the following to work:
inline constexpr std::noop_coroutine_handle noop_coroutine() noexcept {
    return noop_coroutine_handle();
}

// Now users can define constexpr noop_coroutine_handle.
constexpr std::noop_coroutine_handle noop = std::noop_coroutine();


Re: "I understand the standard doesn't require it to be constexpr. But is it intentional or something missing?" - That can only be answered by people actually working with the standard, can't it? The rest of us can only speculate.

"(https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/coroutine#L317)" -- When making claims about parts of the standard library, it would be better to refer to standard documentation, such as cppreference.com, then to infer from a single implementation of the standard library, such as libstdc++. When looking at code, it can be tough to distinguish which details are implementation-specific and which can be expected to be found in any implementation of the standard library.

Thanks for the comments! The default ctor for std::noop_coroutine_handle is not PUBLIC (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/coroutine#L307), but used in std::noop_coroutine. From implementation point of view, it's defined and constexpr, though not visible for users

@DoZerg Will you then clarify your question and add the  [tag:language-lawyer]ing tag? There are people present actively developing the language but there are also those who can dig up motivating notes for different decisions in the evulution of the language. Speculation doesn't fit well here.

Coroutine is a runtime thing, does it make sense to define it as constexpr?

@TedLyngmo Added the tag. Please feel free to improve the question content if you think necessary. Thanks!

@TedLyngmo I'm not sure if language-lawyer tag is appropriate. OP asks for rationale, and the standard isn't going to provide that.

The implementation in libstdc++ could be made constexpr. Other compilers use a helper __builtin_coro_noop() which apparently is not constexpr.

@HolyBlackCat I don't have a concrete use case for constexpr noop_coroutine(). But I feel like we should consider a function constexpr unless there is a reason otherwise, not vice versa. So what I'm asking is either a change to the function signature, or some texts in the standard of why not. IMHO, it'd be more elegant and consistent if all kinds of coroutine_handle can be constexpr, though I appreciate there might be some cases I didn't think of.

@HolyBlackCat No, I didn't mean that it would be found in the standard. All the proposals I've read have had some sort of "motivating notes" though. Those are the notes those of us that wasn't present when the proposal was finally accepted into the standard will have to rely on for a rationale.
